# Relics of the republican calendar

Tags: histoire

Are there any language relics in French from the names of the months and days in the republican calendar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not much. Still, there is a famous book named *Germinal* by Émile Zola, which is named after a month of the republican calendar. Some people may (very rarely) use the expression *« C’est Germinal »* to depict something as horrific.

Answer (score 9):

There are still some historical events referred to by their 'republican calendar' name, see [coup d'état du 18 brumaire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coup_d%27%C3%89tat_du_18_brumaire)' for an example.

Answer (score 5):

In works about history, events that happened when the Republican calendar was in force often have their dates stated with respect to that calendar. This is true even of modern texts.

Answer (score 2):

Language as such, maybe not, but I believe laws passed during that time would still bear the republican date. The month names have been reused by some cities as street names, too.

Answer (score 2):

Une grande banque française a choisi les noms de ***Messidor*** et ***Fructidor*** pour nommer deux de ses produits de placements financiers, ces noms ont été choisis certainement à cause du fait qu'ils évoquent les moissons (Messidor) et les récoltes (Fructidor).

La [**sauce Thermidor**](http://www.recettes-et-terroirs.com/recette.php?id=28164), crée au 19 <sup>e</sup> siècle, est une sauce qui accompagne souvent homard et langouste.

En histoire on peut parle d'« [**un thermidor**](http://bit.ly/2alWN7z) » terme de Thermidor est parfois employé par les historiens pour parler d'une contre révolution (référence à la [chute de Robespierre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chute_de_Robespierre))

Une chaîne de magasins bio s’appelle **Prairial**.

Answer (score 1):

Les frégates de surveillance de la Marine nationale, qui surveillent nos zone maritimes ultramarines, portent le nom de mois du calendrier républicain.

> Floréal (La Réunion)
>
> Nivôse (La Réunion)
>
> Prairial (Tahiti)
>
> Vendémiaire (Nouvelle Calédonie)
>
> Ventôse (Martinique)
>
> Germinal (Martinique)